# Multiple issues using MySQL migration tool

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database-migration

I am trying to migrate my database from MS SQL 2000 to MySQL using Migration tool in MySQL. When I am doing so, I am getting following warnings:

1) Collation changes `SQL_Latin1` to  `UTF8_General_CI`. I am worried about this as my tables contains encrypted data, does this collateral changes affect that?

2) `BIT` field changes to `TINYINT(1)`. MySQL has `BIT` field, than why it is changing to `TINYINT`?

All these were warnings, but also many tables and data are not created. They are missing.
So, I picked one table among them, say `tblProducts`.

When I am trying to migrate this table, I am getting following error :

```
Migrating data... wbcopytables.exe --odbc-source=DSN=SwiplODBC;DATABASE=;UID= --target=root@127.0.0.1:3306 --progress --passwords-from-stdin --thread-count=1 --table-file=c:\users\xxxx\appdata\local\temp\tmp5ffenq \users\xxxx\appdata\local\temp\tmp5ffenq `SWIPL11009`.`tblProducts`:

Copying 83 columns of 102854 rows from table [SWIPL11009].[dbo].[tblProducts] ERROR: `SWIPL11009`.`tblProducts`:Type mismatch fetching field 40 (should be float, was MYSQL_TYPE_DOUBLE) `SWIPL11009`.`tblProducts`:Finished copying 0 rows in 0m01s  
 08:43 [INF][      copytable]: Opening ODBC connection to DSN=SwiplODBC;DATABASE=;UID=;PWD=XXX' 
 08:43 [INF][      copytable]: ODBC connection to 'DSN=SwiplODBC;DATABASE=;UID=;PWD=' opened 
 08:43 [INF][      copytable]: Connecting to MySQL server at 127.0.0.1:3306 with user root 
 08:43 [INF][      copytable]: Connection to MySQL opened 
 ***08:43 [WRN][      copytable]: Invalid timestamp literal detected: ''***
```

Actually I don't have any `timestamp` field, all are `datetime`, and set `null` by default.
Looking forward for some suggestion and solutions.

Thanks.

Comment: Collation applies to text columns. We'd need to know how you store your encrypted data but I presume it's either a binary column or some sort of US-ASCII compatible encoding. (Apart from that, MySQL Workbench is quite a buggy piece of code IMHO.)

Comment: Did you already report [a bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68285)?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario : Yes, I already Reported bug. And happy to say that, I imported my all tables using SQLyog.